# Is it possible to run a server and initialize multiple socket on the same port in Node?

Tags: node.js

I would like to create a server that listens on port 8080, for example. Then I would like to initialize multiple sockets using local port 8080 that connect to additional peers. The purpose of this is to create a peer to peer network, so peers listen on and initialize connections with other peers on the same port.

Answer (score 0):

In order to perform peer to peer connectivity on web, you have to use WebRTC. This is also possible with socket.io. So actually you server won't listen to multiple sockets in same port, but act as a STUN/TURN server in order to introduce different clients. I have written a simple explanation in this [article](https://medium.com/@janithkasun/what-is-webrtc-peer-to-peer-in-web-4786b44db16b). Please read it for further clarifications.

In a peer to peer network you may have to write the code in client side, (since the server may not control the network after peer discovery) instead of writing login in backend.

Also follow this [article](https://blog.jscrambler.com/mixed-signals-with-socket-io-and-webrtc/) for more information about how develop WebRTC network with socket.io.